# How to use version numbers for interface in application with plugins?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, coding-style

I want to write a program that will allow writing plugins for it.
The program will contain SDK with some DLLs libraries that will facilitate the development of the plugins.

However, I am pretty sure that over time the SDK will change, so some kind of version number for the SDK and plugins is needed. The SDK consists of many DLLs.

Also, I don't want that the plugin developer will be able to forget to do something that is needed for the mechanism.

I can think of two ways:

- Using a constant compile time **int VERSION = 1** . Each plugin somehow (I don't know how exactly), takes this constant, and it is added to the DLL as compile time constant. When a plugin is loaded
- Using same AssemblyVersion for all SDK modules. When a plugin is loaded, check that the assembly version of the plugin is lower than current SDK assembly version. In that case, I need to synchronize somehow the program version and SDK version.

So, I am not sure about how to do both.

### Do you have any idea?

Comment: I suspect your plugins will need some sort of InitPlugin() call - why not have this take a MinSDKversion and a MaxSDKversion parameter and return a HandshakedSDKversion, so the plugin can tell your app which SDKs it can target and your app can chose how to talk to it.

Comment: @EugenRieck,  I think you should make this comment an answer. Also, it would be great if you could elaborate on this "min"/"max" mechanism

Comment: Working on it, takes a few mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by @Andrey this is an elaboration of my comment to the OQ:

Plugins (as in plugin assemblies) will most commonly contain a classm, that implements an interface such as `IMyPlugin`

In most cases this inteface will need to have a method like `InitPlugin()`, that allows the plugin to set up its structures etc, i.e. to initialize.

This InitPlugin() will in itself want most often call something like RegisterPlugin() in the main program to register its functionality with the application. This is typically also achieved with an interface such as `IMyPluginHost`.

Now as long as you keep these interfaces so generic, that they themselfes don't need to change, you can easily add version handshake with this sequence:

```
public interface IMyPluginHost
{
  public int RegisterPlugin(int FunctionalityGroup, object WorkerBee, int MinSDKVersion, int MaxSDKVersion);
  ... //Whatever you need to allow the plugin to call into the app
}

public interface IMyPlugin
{
  public int InitPlugin(IMyPluginHost myhost); //Return value is hust an error code
  ... //Whatever you need to allow the app to call into the plugin
}
```

Now when the app decides to load a plugin, it will create its internal plugin host class that implements `IMyPluginHost`, then physically load the plugin, get an `IMyPlugin` to its class and call

```
((IMyPlugin)pluginClass).InitPlugin(this)
```

The plugin can now cycle its functionality groups (which groups there are depends on your app - if it is e.g. an image manipulation app, there might be functionality groups such as Filter, FileTypeImport, FileTypeExport, Brush, ... each with their interface) and for each instantiate a worker object, then call

```
host.RegisterPlugin(FunctionalityGroup, WorkerBee, MinSDKVersion, MaxSDKVersion);
```

with host being the `IMyPluginHost` it got as as anrgument to `InitPlugin()`.

So if the plugin is built only against SDK V5 MinSDKVersion and MaxSDKVersion will both be 5. But if a smart plugin can handle SDK Versions 2-5 MinSDKVersion will be 2 and MaxSDKVersion will be 5. This allows one plugin to work with different versions of your app (and thus SDK)

The app itself also has a range of SDK versions it supports, say 3-6. So in this case the call to `RegisterPlugin()` would return 5, as this is the highest SDK version that both partners support. Again this gives your app a way to support older plugins, so that upgrading your app doesn't break all third-party plugins.

Negative return values for `InitPlugin()` would be errors.

After this is done, the plugin has a reference to the host and knows about what it can expect from it in terms of SDK version and vice versa.

Comment: Some rationale for the use of interfaces vs. abstract classes etc: You might want to load your plugins into a separate AppDomain. The easiest way to avoid also loading them into your main AppDomain is to talk ONLY via interfaces in both directions.

Comment: Did you mean  ((IMyPlugin
)pluginClass).InitPlugin(this)  instead of ((IMyPluginHost)pluginClass).InitPlugin(this) in your answer, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I would no introduce a versioning concept at all.
If you think what the `Host` needs:

- possibility to locate and load plugins
- posibility to interact with them, by exposing a features to the plugins or recovering from them.

How to manage the dev changes in `SDK`?

First of all: all changes *have to be* as much as it possible back compatible.

What if it's btw not possible?

Well, the `Host` *searches* for exposed functionality inside a loaded plugin, if it fails to find, it leads to 3 possible conclusions.

1. Plugin is written for newer version of `Host` but used by old one
2. Plugin is written for older version of `Host` but used by newer.
3. it's not a valud plugin.

For sure, you can include a required `Host` version like a attribute on the `MainClass` of your plugin and `Host` can search for it, this can help for easy identification of *possible* version conflict. Why *possible*, cause the version could be different but the architecture can be pretty reliable and no need to plugin supplier to change something inside it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the mention of making SDK/API changes backward compatible.

Comment: What if the interface has not changed, but the implementation did? Should I rename the interface somehow?

Comment: @Andrey: changing an interface *name* is a **absolute crucial** change. Remember that the `Interface` and methods it exposes is the only link that Plugins and Host can use. So , sure, you *can* change it, but you will break backward compatibility. The *beauty* and actual sence of interface that you *can* change implementation without changing interface and without breaking backward compatibility, at least on `host-plugin` binding level.

Comment: @Tigran, thanks, I understand it. Actually what I meant is that the implementation changed, but in such a way that the new plugin will break. Maybe in that case, the interface should be changed.

Comment: @andrey: if you change interface name, old plugin *will* break, if you change only implementation, old *may* break, but may be not, depends on implementation. In this case on rescue can come, for example, esplicit `supporting host version` declared by plugin. The complex stuff is that after every implementation change of your `host` you should know which *old* versions of plugin you may still support, which versions not, depending on *what exactly was changed in Host implementation*. may be in your case, to make things easier, you just can say if the version is different => it's not supported.

Comment: @andrey: but it depends on your clients, your business how you gonna manage versioning cobflict.

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstract class that all plugins have to implement and put your version checking logic in it i.e. a function that returns the major, minor and build number the plugin is compatible with that you call after initializing the plugin.

Depending on how strict you want to check your versions you can then respond in the application. (I also recommend you use SemVer for the versions, you'll see why as your API matures)

This also allows you to check for versions too old or too new to run on your application.

Comment: How can I be sure that this function will return the version of the SDK that the developer worked with? I don't trust the developer of the plugin.

Comment: Your abstract class is in a dll you hand of to the developer.If you're paranoid you can sign it to prevent tampering.